# Black screen when opening games

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, gaming

I'm getting a black screen when opening new games, sometimes with a mouse pointer.

Old games run fine but games like FIFA 2013, FIFA 2014 and Need For Speed won't run.

This problem suddenly occurred after my little cousin played on my PC.

- Processor: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G540 @ 2.50GHz 2.50 GHZ
- Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB
- Graphics Intel(R) HD Graphics
- Gaming graphics 1648 MB Total available graphics memory
- Primary hard disk 32GB Free (49GB Total)

Graphics:

```
  Display adapter type Intel(R) HD Graphics 
  Total available graphics memory 1648 MB 
        Dedicated graphics memory 256 MB 
        Dedicated system memory 0 MB 
        Shared system memory 1392 MB 
  Display adapter driver version 9.17.10.3517 
  Primary monitor resolution 1440x900 
  DirectX version DirectX 10
```

Comment: Did you ask if your cousin changed anything?

Comment: he pressed random buttons at the bios screen but i have restored the default settings and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your sound settings are running at 44,100 khz; if he accidentally changed this, it can cause many games working with onboard sound card drivers or poorly coded proprietary sound drivers to crash.

You'll see the same problem with a lot of the LEGO games, Bioshock, Mass Effect, Borderlands, and Tomb Raiders.

If that doesn't work, copy and paste your dxdiag to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and I'll see if I can help you more.